# adding custom icons for custom palette in camunda modeler

Tags: javascript, camunda-modeler

We downloaded the source code for the Camunda Modeler
we created a custom palette similar to [this](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-example-custom-controls)

```
export default class CustomPalette {
    constructor(bpmnFactory, create, elementFactory, palette, translate) {
        this.bpmnFactory = bpmnFactory;
        this.create = create;
        this.elementFactory = elementFactory;
        this.translate = translate;

        palette.registerProvider(this);
    }

    getPaletteEntries(element) {
        const {
            bpmnFactory,
            create,
            elementFactory,
            translate
        } = this;

        function createServiceTask(event) {
            const shape = elementFactory.createShape({
                type: 'bpmn:ServiceTask'
            });

            create.start(event, shape);
        }

        function createCustomServiceTask(templateId, serviceTaskName) {
            return function(event) {
                const businessObject = bpmnFactory.create('bpmn:ServiceTask', {
                    name: serviceTaskName,
                    "camunda:modelerTemplate": templateId
                });

                const shape = elementFactory.createShape({
                    type: 'bpmn:ServiceTask',
                    businessObject: businessObject
                });

                create.start(event, shape);
            }
        }

        return {
            'test-separator' : {
                group: 'test',
                separator: true
            },
            'create.report-success': {
                group: 'test',
                className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
                title: translate('Test - Report Success'),
                action: {
                    dragstart: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.workflow.camunda.SuccessDelegate', 'Report Success'),
                    click: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.workflow.camunda.SuccessDelegate', 'Report Success')
                }
            },
            'create.report-failure': {
                group: 'test',
                className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
                title: translate('Test - Report Failure'),
                action: {
                    dragstart: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.workflow.camunda.FailDelegate', 'Report Failure'),
                    click: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.workflow.camunda.FailDelegate', 'Report Failure')
                }
            },
            'create.perform-device-control-check': {
                group: 'test',
                className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
                title: translate('Test - Perform Device Control Check'),
                action: {
                    dragstart: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.PerfomrDeviceControlCheck', 'Perform Device Control Check'),
                    click: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.PerfomrDeviceControlCheck', 'Perform Device Control Check')
                }
            },
            'create.perform-device-control-commands': {
                group: 'test',
                className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
                title: translate('Test - Perform Device Control Commands'),
                action: {
                    dragstart: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.PerformDeviceControlCommands', 'Perform Device Control Commands'),
                    click: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.PerformDeviceControlCommands', 'Perform Device Control Commands')
                }
            },
            'create.validate-room': {
                group: 'test',
                className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
                title: translate('Test - Validate Room'),
                action: {
                    dragstart: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.ValidateRoom', 'Validate Room'),
                    click: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.ValidateRoom', 'Validate Room')
                }
            },
            'create.perform-device-control-result-verification': {
                group: 'test',
                className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
                title: translate('Test - Perform Device Control Result Verification'),
                action: {
                    dragstart: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.PerformDeviceControlResultVerification', 'Perform Device Control Result Verification'),
                    click: createCustomServiceTask('com.test.test.delegate.camunda.PerformDeviceControlResultVerification', 'Perform Device Control Result Verification')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

CustomPalette.$inject = [
    'bpmnFactory',
    'create',
    'elementFactory',
    'palette',
    'translate'
];
```

if you look above you will see this line

```
className: 'bpmn-icon-service-task',
```

this seems to define the icon used for it.  When searching through the project for that string
i come across an instance in dist\css\bpmn.css

```
.bpmn-icon-service-task:before { content: '\e856'; } /* 'î¡–' */
```

However i don't understand what \e856 really references or how to add an entry here for a custom icon

it seems to me like this `content: '\e165'` is some kind of convention or defined process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS 'content' uses the hexadecimal entity of a character
(http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/). Your example hex **\e856** is **59478** in decimal
(https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html)

The Camunda Modeler uses BPMN.io, which uses its own font to define the BPMN symbols (https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-font). The font elements (icons) are defined here:
https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-font/blob/master/resources/font-config.json

```
 {
      "uid": "0a43fd26041da75f0753b52e45a707e9",
      "css": "service-task",
      "code": 59478,
      "src": "custom_icons",
      "selected": true,
      "svg": {
        "path": "M214.8 105C107.5 105 20 192.1 20 299.3L20 700.8C20 807.9 107.5 895 214.8 895L785.2 895C892.5 895 980 807.9 980 700.8L980 299.3C980 192.1 892.5 105 785.2 105L214.8 105ZM214.8 165L785.2 165C860.4 165 920 224.4 920 299.3L920 700.8C920 775.6 860.4 835 785.2 835L214.8 835C139.6 835 80 775.6 80 700.8L80 299.3C80 224.4 139.6 165 214.8 165ZM251.4 215.4C251.4 227 251.4 238.6 251.4 250.2 241.5 253 232.5 256.9 224 261.7L199.1 237 152.5 283.9 177.4 308.5C172.6 317.1 168.8 326.3 166.2 335.8L130.9 335.9 130.9 401.9 166.6 401.8C169.8 414.7 176.9 426.3 184 436.7L184 379.8 152.8 379.9 152.8 357.8 183.9 357.7 185.6 348.9C188.1 336 193.2 323.8 200.4 312.8L205.3 305.3 183.5 283.8 199.2 268 221.1 289.6 228.5 284.6C239.8 277.1 252.3 272.1 264.6 269.5L273.4 267.7 273.3 237.4 295.8 237.4 295.7 267.5 304.6 267.5 354.8 267.5C349.2 260.9 326.3 252.3 317.7 249.9L317.9 215.4C293.3 215.4 274.1 215.4 251.4 215.4ZM313.8 278.6L313.8 313.3C304 316.1 294.9 320 286.4 324.8L261.5 300.2 214.9 347 239.8 371.7C235 380.3 231.2 389.4 228.6 399L193.3 399 193.3 465 229 464.9C231.8 474.7 235.7 483.6 240.5 492.1L214.9 517.5 262.1 563.8 287.5 538.5C296.2 543.3 305.4 547.1 315 549.7L315.1 585.6C337.7 585.8 361.9 585.7 381.2 585.7L381.2 549.3C391.1 546.6 400.2 542.6 408.7 537.8L434.1 562.9 480.7 516.1 455.3 491C460.1 482.4 463.8 473.2 466.5 463.6L501 463.4 501 397.5 466.1 397.7C463.3 387.9 459.4 379 454.6 370.5L478.8 346.3 431.7 300 407.6 324.2C398.9 319.4 389.7 315.6 380.1 313L380.3 278.6 313.8 278.6 313.8 278.6ZM335.7 300.5L358.3 300.5 358.1 330.6 367 332.4C379.9 334.9 392.3 339.9 403.3 347.1L410.8 352 431.8 330.9 447.7 346.5 426.6 367.6 431.7 375.1C439.1 386.3 444 398.5 446.8 411L448.6 419.7 479.1 419.5 479.1 441.6 448.8 441.8 447.1 450.6C444.5 463.5 439.5 475.7 432.3 486.7L427.3 494.3 449.6 516.2 434 532 411.6 510 404.2 514.9C392.9 522.3 380.5 527.5 368.1 530L359.3 531.8 359.3 563.8C353.3 563.8 346.7 563.8 337 563.8L336.9 532 328.1 530.3C315.2 527.7 302.8 522.7 291.8 515.5L284.4 510.7 262 532.9 246.1 517.4 268.5 495 263.4 487.5C256 476.3 251 464.2 248.3 451.7L246.4 442.9 215.2 443 215.2 420.9 246.3 420.9 248 412C250.5 399.2 255.6 386.9 262.8 375.9L267.7 368.4 245.9 346.9 261.6 331.1 283.5 352.7 290.9 347.7C302.3 340.3 314.3 335.4 327 332.6L335.8 330.8 335.7 300.5ZM347.4 381C320.2 381 298 403.2 298 430.4 298 457.5 320.2 479.7 347.4 479.7 374.5 479.7 396.7 457.5 396.7 430.4 396.7 403.2 374.5 381 347.4 381ZM347.4 402.9C362.6 402.9 374.8 415.1 374.8 430.4 374.8 445.7 362.6 457.8 347.4 457.8 332.1 457.8 319.9 445.7 319.9 430.4 319.9 415.1 332.1 402.9 347.4 402.9Z",
        "width": 1000
      },
      "search": [
        "service-task"
      ]
    },
```

Line 1302 defines the code 59478 for the symbol in use
https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-font/blob/b366fdef83c700898a664cb32d57d63618b36154/resources/font-config.json#L1302

You can see how it defines the code 59478 for the SVG:
https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-font/blob/b366fdef83c700898a664cb32d57d63618b36154/resources/font-config.json#L1305

The How-to https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-font/blob/master/docs/HOWTO.md describes how the font was created and can be extended.

You may also find this overview helpful:
https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/bpmn-io/bpmn-font/master/dist/demo.html